# How to put multiple columns into a kivy RecycleView?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I want to put the data of a (csv-)table into a kivy recycleview.

I managed to insert multiple columns with one row, if i assign a fixed text to the Labels in the kv, but i can't get it to fill the labels with data from a dictionary list. This is the code so far, that i use to test the concept:

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
import csv

items = [{'SP1': 'Artikelnummer', 'SP2': 'Name', 'SP3': 'Groesse'},
    {'SP1': '510001', 'SP2': 'Big Pump', 'SP3': '1.50 L'},
    {'SP1': '523001', 'SP2': 'Leonie Still', 'SP3': '1.50 L'},
    {'SP1': '641301', 'SP2': 'Cola Mix', 'SP3': '1.50 L'}
]

class Tabelle(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Tabelle, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def insert_SP(self, data):
        for i in data:
            self.spalte1_SP = i['SP1']
            #print(self.spalte1_SP)
            self.spalte2_SP = i['SP2']
            self.spalte3_SP = i['SP3']

Builder.load_string('''
<Tabelle>:
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    spalte1_SP: 'spalte1'
    spalte2_SP: 'spalte2'
    spalte3_SP: 'spalte3'
    Label:
        id: Spalte1
        text: root.spalte1_SP
    Label:
        id: Spalte2
        text: root.spalte2_SP
    Label:
        id: Spalte3
        text: root.spalte3_SP

<RV>:
    viewclass: 'Tabelle'
    RecycleBoxLayout:
        default_size: None, dp(20)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'
''')

class RV(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        #self.data = []
        x = Tabelle()
        x.insert_SP(items)

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RV()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

I expect to see the data from **items** in 3 columns, but they stay empty for some reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is empty because `data` was not populated.

## Solution

- Remove all codings in `class Tabelle()`
- Add `pass` into `class Tabelle()`
- Add the following into constructor, `__init__()` of `class RV()`

### Snippets

```
self.data = [{'spalte1_SP': str(x['SP1']), 'spalte2_SP': str(x['SP2']), 'spalte3_SP': str(x['SP3'])} for x in items]
```

### [Kivy RecycleView » data](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.recycleview.html)

> The view is generatad by processing the [data](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.recycleview.html#kivy.uix.recycleview.RecycleView.data), essentially a list
>   of dicts, and uses these dicts to generate instances of the viewclass
>   as required.
>
> ```
> data
> ```
>
> The data used by the current view adapter. This is a list of dicts
>   whose keys map to the corresponding property names of the viewclass.
>
> data is an AliasProperty that gets and sets the data used to generate
>   the views.

### Example

#### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

items = [{'SP1': 'Artikelnummer', 'SP2': 'Name', 'SP3': 'Groesse'},
         {'SP1': '510001', 'SP2': 'Big Pump', 'SP3': '1.50 L'},
         {'SP1': '523001', 'SP2': 'Leonie Still', 'SP3': '1.50 L'},
         {'SP1': '641301', 'SP2': 'Cola Mix', 'SP3': '1.50 L'}
         ]


class Tabelle(BoxLayout):
    pass


Builder.load_string('''
<Tabelle>:
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    spalte1_SP: 'spalte1'
    spalte2_SP: 'spalte2'
    spalte3_SP: 'spalte3'
    Label:
        id: SP1
        text: root.spalte1_SP
    Label:
        id: SP2
        text: root.spalte2_SP
    Label:
        id: SP3
        text: root.spalte3_SP

<RV>:
    viewclass: 'Tabelle'
    RecycleBoxLayout:
        default_size: None, dp(20)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'
''')


class RV(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.data = [{'spalte1_SP': str(x['SP1']), 'spalte2_SP': str(x['SP2']), 'spalte3_SP': str(x['SP3'])} for x in items]


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RV()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

### Output

[image: Result]

Comment: I'm speechless. After sitting for the whole day on this and seeing how simple the solution actually looks... you can't believe how much this helped me! Thank you!

Comment: You are most welcome! An alternate solution is to use a `viewclass: 'Label'`, `RecycleGridLayout:`, `cols: 3`, and `self.data = [{'text': val} for row in items for val in row.values()]`.

Comment: Thank you, looks more versatile for when i want to add more columns. Will definitely test it out.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the previous solution, here's a code whose interpretation is much easier. Additionally, one of the column is a checkbox.

Result:
[image]

Python file:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

# data
items = [{'number': '510001', 'name': 'Big Pump', 'size': '1.50 L', 'in_stock': True},
         {'number': '523001', 'name': 'Leonie Still', 'size': '1.60 L', 'in_stock': False},
         {'number': '641301', 'name': 'Apple Mix', 'size': '1.30 L', 'in_stock': True},
         {'number': '681301', 'name': 'Orange Mix', 'size': '1.40 L', 'in_stock': True}
        ]


class MultiFieldLine(BoxLayout):
    # class layout defined in kv file
    pass


class AppGUI(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.rv.data = [{'label_1': str(x['number']), 'label_2': str(x['name']), 'label_3': str(x['size']), 'checkbox_1': x['in_stock']} for x in items]


class ExploreRecycleViewMultipleFieldApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return AppGUI()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ExploreRecycleViewMultipleFieldApp().run()
```

KV file:

```
<MultiFieldLine>:
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    label_1: ''
    label_2: ''
    label_3: ''
    checkbox_1: False
    Label:
        text: root.label_1
    Label:
        text: root.label_2
    Label:
        text: root.label_3
    CheckBox:
        active: root.checkbox_1
<AppGUI>: # inherit from GridLayout
    rv: rv_id
    cols:  1
    rows: 2
    GridLayout: # col titles
        cols: 4
        rows: 1
        size_hint_y: 0.04
        Label:
            text: 'Number'
        Label:
            text: 'Name'
        Label:
            text: 'Size'
        Label
            text: 'In stock'
    GridLayout: # data
        cols: 1
        rows: 1
        size_hint_y: 0.96
        RecycleView:
            id: rv_id
            viewclass: 'MultiFieldLine'
            RecycleBoxLayout:
                default_size: None, dp(20)
                default_size_hint: 1, None
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
                orientation: 'vertical'
```

The version below adds row selection as well as a larger label width for the name column and a method in the gui class called each time a line is selected.:

Result:
[image]

Python file:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty
from kivy.uix.behaviors import FocusBehavior
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

# data
from kivy.uix.recycleboxlayout import RecycleBoxLayout
from kivy.uix.recycleview.layout import LayoutSelectionBehavior
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior

items = [{'number': '510001', 'name': 'Big Pump', 'size': '1.50 L', 'in_stock': True},
         {'number': '523001', 'name': 'Leonie Still very, very,very long, long name', 'size': '1.60 L', 'in_stock': False},
         {'number': '641301', 'name': 'Apple Mix', 'size': '1.30 L', 'in_stock': True},
         {'number': '681301', 'name': 'Orange Mix', 'size': '1.40 L', 'in_stock': True}
        ]


class MultiFieldLine(RecycleDataViewBehavior, BoxLayout):
    ''' class layout defined in kv file '''
    index = None
    selected = BooleanProperty(False)
    selectable = BooleanProperty(True)
    
    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        ''' Catch and handle the view changes '''
        self.rv = rv
        self.appGUI = rv.appGUI
        self.index = index
        
        return super(MultiFieldLine, self).refresh_view_attrs(
            rv, index, data)
    
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        ''' Add selection on touch down '''
        if super(MultiFieldLine, self).on_touch_down(touch):
            return True
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and self.selectable:
            return self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index, touch)
    
    def apply_selection(self, rv, index, is_selected):
        # instance variable used in .kv file to change the selected item
        # color !
        self.selected = is_selected
  
        if is_selected:
            self.appGUI.outputSelectedData(rv.data[index])


class SelectableRecycleBoxLayout(FocusBehavior, LayoutSelectionBehavior,
                                 RecycleBoxLayout):
    ''' Adds selection and focus behaviour to the view. '''
    
    # required to authorise unselecting a selected item
    touch_deselect_last = BooleanProperty(True)


class AppGUI(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.rv.data = [{'label_1': str(x['number']), 'label_2': str(x['name']), 'label_3': str(x['size']), 'checkbox_1': x['in_stock']} for x in items]

    def outputSelectedData(self, data):
    # method called when a line is selected
        print(data)

class ExploreRecycleViewMultipleFieldBoxLayoutApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return AppGUI()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ExploreRecycleViewMultipleFieldBoxLayoutApp().run()
```

KV file:

```
<MultiFieldLine>: # inherit from RecycleDataViewBehavior and BoxLayout
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    label_1: ''
    label_2: ''
    label_3: ''
    checkbox_1: False
    # add selection background
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (1, 0, 0, 1) if self.selected else (.0, 0.9, .1, .3)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
        Color:
            rgba: (0, 0.9, .1, .3)
    Label:
        size_hint_x: 0.1
        text: root.label_1
    Label:
        size_hint_x: 0.7
        text: root.label_2
    Label:
        size_hint_x: 0.1
        text: root.label_3
    CheckBox:
        size_hint_x: 0.1
        active: root.checkbox_1
<AppGUI>: # inherit from GridLayout
    rv: rv_id
    cols:  1
    rows: 2
    GridLayout: # col titles
        cols: 4
        rows: 1
        size_hint_y: 0.04
        Label:
            size_hint_x: 0.1
            text: 'Number'
        Label:
            size_hint_x: 0.7
            text: 'Name'
        Label:
            size_hint_x: 0.1
            text: 'Size'
        Label
            size_hint_x: 0.1
            text: 'In stock'
    GridLayout: # data
        cols: 1
        rows: 1
        size_hint_y: 0.96
        RecycleView:
            id: rv_id
            appGUI: root
            viewclass: 'MultiFieldLine'
            SelectableRecycleBoxLayout:
                default_size: None, dp(20)
                default_size_hint: 1, None
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
                orientation: 'vertical'
```