# RecycleView with multiple colums with different class

Tags: python, kivy, widget, ids, kivy-recycleview

I have a kind of major problem here. I want to create a list at the bottom of my app. I have a dictionary which works on this guy's solution: [How to put multiple columns into a kivy RecycleView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55692120/how-to-put-multiple-columns-into-a-kivy-recycleview)

HOWEVER, I want to add that widget with button. Everything looks fine but I have problem with ids.

Please take a look at it, "FinalList" class cant find variables.

When you run it click "Calculate selections" it adds another class which has another button called "Confirm". Click "Confirm", it should add list at the bottom but it does not.

here is my main.py code;

```
from kivy.animation import Parallel
from kivy.app import App
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.checkbox import CheckBox
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder
from functools import partial
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty, BooleanProperty

#Window.size=((640/1.5),(960/1.5))


items = [{'SP1': 'Artikelnummer', 'SP2': 'Name', 'SP3': 'Groesse'},
        {'SP1': '510001', 'SP2': 'Big Pump', 'SP3': '1.50 L'},
        {'SP1': '523001', 'SP2': 'Leonie Still', 'SP3': '1.50 L'},
        {'SP1': '641301', 'SP2': 'Cola Mix', 'SP3': '1.50 L'}
        ]



class MainWidget(Widget):

    cal2= ObjectProperty()
    cal4= ObjectProperty()
    
    def btn4(self):
        self.cal2 = MaterialS() #MaterialS is my class with different widget
        self.ids.scd.add_widget(self.cal2, index=0)  #scd is the id of my main widget, index =0 help me to insert to the bottom

    def btn8(self):
        self.cal4 = RV() **#HERE I CALL THE RV CLASS**
        self.ids.scd.add_widget(self.cal4, index=0) 


class SecondPage(ScrollView):
    pass

class Calculation(GridLayout):
    pass

class MaterialS(BoxLayout):
    def btn7(self,x):
        self.ids[x].disabled= True
    def btn9(self,x):
        self.ids[x].disabled= True


class FinalList(BoxLayout):
    pass

class RV(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.data = [{'spalte1_SP': str(x['SP1']), 'spalte2_SP': str(x['SP2']), 'spalte3_SP': str(x['SP3'])} for x in items]


class MyApp(MDApp):
    pass

MyApp().run()
```

here is my.kv file;

```
MainWidget:
<MainWidget>:
    ScreenManager:
        id: scmanager
        size: root.width, root.height
        Screen:
            id: scndpage
            name: "second"
            SecondPage:
                Calculation:
                    id:scd            
                    cols:1 
                    height: self.minimum_height 
                    row_default_height: "70dp"
                    size_hint_y: None
                    spacing:"10dp"
                    canvas.before:
                        Rectangle:
                            pos: self.pos
                            size: self.size
                    Button:
                        id: cslect
                        text:"Calculate Selections"
                        on_press: app.root.btn4()


<MaterialS>:
    pading:"10dp"
    spacing:"10dp"
    size_hint: 1, None
    height: "250dp" 
    orientation:"vertical"
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: 1, 1
        orientation:"horizontal"
        Label:  
            text:"cutter head material"
            color: 0,0,0,1



    Button:
        id: btnStd
        text:"Confirm"
        on_press: app.root.btn8()
        on_release: root.btn9("btnStd")


<Optionals>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

    Button:
        id: btnStd
        text:"Confirm"
        on_press: app.root.btn8()
        on_release: root.btn9("btnStd")



<FinalList>:
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    spalte1_SP: 'spalte1'
    spalte2_SP: 'spalte2'
    spalte3_SP: 'spalte3'
    Label:
        id: SP1
        text: app.root.spalte1_SP **#HERE IS THE MAIN PROBLEM**
    Label:
        id: SP2
        text: app.root.spalte2_SP **#HERE IS THE MAIN PROBLEM**
    Label:
        id: SP3
        text: app.root.spalte3_SP **#HERE IS THE MAIN PROBLEM**


<RV>:
    viewclass: 'FinalList'
    RecycleBoxLayout:
        default_size: None, dp(20)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to correct your references to the properties of the `FinalList`. Like this:

```
<FinalList>:
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    spalte1_SP: 'spalte1'
    spalte2_SP: 'spalte2'
    spalte3_SP: 'spalte3'
    
    Label:
        id: SP1
        text: root.spalte1_SP #**#HERE IS THE MAIN PROBLEM**
    Label:
        id: SP2
        text: root.spalte2_SP #**#HERE IS THE MAIN PROBLEM**
    Label:
        id: SP3
        text: root.spalte3_SP #**#HERE IS THE MAIN PROBLEM**
```